# replace Figure in FigureCanvas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

Is it possible to replace `Figure` in `FigureCanvas` (see funcs `plot` & `plot_data`)?
I thought, it's possible to use `fig.set_canvas(self)` (see `plot` func), but it doesn't work.

PS: I know, it's possible to clear figure with `self.axes.clear()`, but it doesn't fit me. I'd like to save `Figure` in some map in the future (caching)

```
class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, width = 5, height = 5, dpi = 100):
        self.fig_width = width
        self.fig_height = height
        self.fig_dpi = dpi
        fig = Figure(figsize=(self.fig_width, self.fig_height), dpi=self.fig_dpi)
        self.axes = fig.subplots(2,3)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)


    def plot(self, datatest_data):
        fig = self.plot_data(new_data)
        fig.set_canvas(self)

    def plot_data(self, new_data):
        len_keys = len(new_data.index)
        fig = Figure(figsize=(30, 5*len_keys), dpi=self.fig_dpi)
        self.axes = fig.subplots(len_keys, 2)
        .....
        return fig
```

Comment: Would it also work to just replace the axes instead of the figure? What do you need the figure for? Please provide a working MWE. It is not clear how your sample code is supposed to work.